# "Optimize CSS Delivery" - Why Google uses this much code to load CSS file?

Tags: css, performance, pagespeed

This is [Google Optimize CSS Delivery page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery). At the bottom google suggests use this code to load CSS file at the end of the page body:

```
  <noscript id="deferred-styles">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="small.css"/>
    </noscript>
    <script>
      var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
        var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
        var replacement = document.createElement("div");
        replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
        document.body.appendChild(replacement)
        addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
      };
      var raf = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
      if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
      else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
    </script>
  </body>
```

My questions is why not just use this one line to do the job? Especially we are in HTML5 world.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="small.css"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a browser is parsing an HTML response, it does so line by line. And when it encounters a `<link>` element, it stops parsing the HTML and goes to fetch the resource set by the element's `href` attribute.

What the code is doing is wrapping the CSS in a `<noscript>` element as a fallback, and instead of blocking the page load, making a request for the CSS after the page has finished loading. It is a way to manually give a `<link>` element similar behavior to the `<script>` element's `defer` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. But the page has been loaded except the the `</body>` tag. Is it important to load CSS file after the  `</body>` tag is parsed?

Comment: In most situations doing this isn't really necessary especially if you use `link[rel="preload"]` for sub resources. The performance gain this achieves only really shows for connections with *very* high ping. And putting it after `</body>` is invalid.